# Air for iOS config panel closes when I click another tab on Flash CS6 on Windows

Tags: air, flash-cs6

Whenever I try to edit configuration in Air (desktop, android or iOS) and I click in another tab, Flash loses focus and the config windows closes. I have googled for anything similiar but I haven't found anything.

Does anybody knows if this is a known issue, or if there is another way to add icons, certificates and permissions in Flash CS6.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: It's not a known issue – it sounds like the install of Flash CS6 is damaged. Have you updated Flash CS6 (version 12.0.0) to the most recent version (12.0.2)? You could add icons, certificates and set permissions by manually modifying the app's XML file, but you shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Yes. I have updated to 12.0.2

I've tried editing permissions modifying XML, but Flash keeps editing it, so I'm not sure what to do. I have reinstalled it several times and it keeps doing the same thing.